# Почему не применяется правило из медиа запроса?

Tags: html, css, media

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему медиа правило зачёркнуто?

Comment: Возможно обычное правило расположено ниже по коду или подключено позже в бандл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Медиа-запрос не добавляет специфичности селектору, поэтому если в конечном файле обычное описание расположено после стилей с медиа-запросом, применится обычный стиль:

```css
.el1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .el1 {
    background: green;
  }
  .el2 {
    background: lime;
  }
}

.el2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="el1">media</div>
<div class="el2">common</div>
```